# Run C++ on Arduino only when rasperry pi asks for it

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

I want to send data to my arduino from raspberry pi to send me sensor values once and then continue to do nothing and pass.  Currently I send a value and then I receive an infinite loop, which I dont want. Here is the code:

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    unsigned long startTime=millis();  
    int phValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    float voltage = phValue * (5/1023.0);
    float ph = (-5.6548 * voltage) + 15.509;
    int dis=SharpIR.distance();
    float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
    float outside_temp = dht.readTemperature();
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
    float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f,h);
    Serial.print(ph); //ph
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(dis);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(h); //humidity
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(f); //outside temp in farenheit
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.println(hif);
  } else {
    ;
  }

}
```

Comment: to receive on Arduino request from Pi you have to run code on Arduino all time and it has to all time check if there is new information. If you will run it every 10 second then it may miss some request and Pi will not get data but empty result.

Comment: yea, that is why i want to send for example a "1" from raspberry pi to arduino. and if the arduino does get a one, send data once then continue listening for a 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Arduino board and Raspberry Pi board should talk to each other over UART. You should only set the baud rate on your devices.

On Arduino side for example, you can setup the Serial connection with:

```cpp
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming string:
    incomingString = Serial.readString();
    Serial.write("Hello Raspberrry");
  }
}
```

On Raspberry side, you should configure your board using [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) tutorial first. Then you need to install PySerial package on your raspberry using `pip3 install pyserial`. Then your board can talk to Arduino using:

```py
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=2.0)

while True:
    port.write("Hello Arduino")
    string = port.readline()
    print(string)

    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: great this is what I was looking for. so basically "serial.available > 0" is waiting for data to be sent to the arduino, and once it is Serial.readString() reads the data that was sent?

Comment: @MikeSandstrom Exactly. So whenever request is received, it enters the `if` statement and sends a data back to raspberry.

Comment: ok, however, I cant break out of the loop once I send the data. I sent the data and entered an infinite loop with my data being sent many times. How do I do it to where I only receive the data once every time i send arduino a message?

Comment: Maybe I can send a 1 to arduino to receive a message. then send a 0 after I received it, where the zero enters the part of the loop that just pass's every time?

Comment: @MikeSandstrom that `loop()` should always be running. Whenever there is a request from Raspberry pi, you enter that `if` and replies. Otherwise you can do something else, or prepare a new data or simply do nothing.

Comment: ok, figured out most of it, however I keep getting error saying 'incomingString' is not defined in that scope.I tried #define incomingString, char incomingString;, int incomingString;